# Residue of root

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

How would one go about calculating $\text{Res}((z-1)^{-3/2},1)$ ? Niavely I thought this was a second order pole and did the following
\begin{align}\text{Res}((z-1)^{-3/2},1) &= \text{Res}(\sqrt{z-1} (z-1)^{-2},1)\\
&= \frac{1}{(2-1)!}\lim_{z \to 1} \frac{d}{dz} \left((z-1)^2 \sqrt{z-1} (z-1)^{-2}\right)\\
&= \lim_{z \to 1} \frac{d}{dz} \sqrt{z-1}\\
&= \lim_{z \to 1} \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{z-1}}\\
&\to \infty
\end{align}
which results in a singularity. WolframAlpha tells me the solution should be zero. Are there general methods for dealing with these kinds of functions?

Comment: There is no residue here. The function has a branch point at $z=1$, not an isolated singularity.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Formally how would one calculate the residue of zero for this case? Or does the definition of the residue as a contour integral around a certain point no longer hold for branch points? If this is the case what definition should one use?

Comment: With the correct branch $(z-1)^{-3/2}$ is analytic at $z=0$ thus its residue is $0$.